# Buildroot gcc headers don't match linux-headers

Tags: gcc, embedded-linux, buildroot

I'm using Buildroot 2018.02.7 to build a simple Linux system for i386 PC, as a precursor to doing the same thing for an embedded ARM system. I keep running into problems like this one, in building the util-linux module:

```
  CC       lib/libcommon_la-path.lo
lib/pager.c:11:17: fatal error: err.h: No such file or directory
 #include <err.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:8596: recipe for target 'lib/libcommon_la-pager.lo' failed
make[3]: *** [lib/libcommon_la-pager.lo] Error 1
```

When I look in the linux-headers source tree in .../output/build/linux-headers-4.13.8, the file is found. But Buildroot is pointing to a different set of headers, the one built into its GCC:

```
devuser@3faf730b4a1b:~/pc/buildroot-2018.02.7/output/build/util-linux-2.31.1$ ../../host/bin/i686-buildroot-linux-uclibc-gcc -print-sysroot
/home/devuser/pc/buildroot-2018.02.7/output/host/i686-buildroot-linux-uclibc/sysroot
devuser@3faf730b4a1b:~/pc/buildroot-2018.02.7/output/build/util-linux-2.31.1$
```

And the two /usr/include subdirectories are significantly different.

Have I missed a configuration setting somewhere in the defconfig file? This is the defconfig:

```
BR2_x86_core2=y
BR2_SSP_REGULAR=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_LINUX_HEADERS_CUSTOM_4_13=y
BR2_UCLIBC_CONFIG="board/pc/dsa_pc_i386_uclibc.config"
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_BUILDROOT_USE_SSP=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_BUILDROOT_CXX=y
BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_GETTY_PORT="tty1"
BR2_ROOTFS_POST_IMAGE_SCRIPT="board/pc/post-image.sh support/scripts/genimage.sh"
BR2_ROOTFS_POST_SCRIPT_ARGS="-c board/pc/genimage-bios.cfg"
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_VERSION=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_VERSION_VALUE="4.13.8"
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_USE_CUSTOM_CONFIG=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_CONFIG_FILE="board/pc/linux.config"
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_INSTALL_TARGET=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_EXT_XENOMAI=y
BR2_PACKAGE_BUSYBOX_CONFIG="board/pc/dsa_pc_i386_busybox.config"
BR2_PACKAGE_LINUX_FIRMWARE=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LINUX_FIRMWARE_ATHEROS_9170=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LINUX_FIRMWARE_ATHEROS_9271=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LINUX_FIRMWARE_IWLWIFI_3160=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LINUX_FIRMWARE_IWLWIFI_3168=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LINUX_FIRMWARE_IWLWIFI_5000=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LINUX_FIRMWARE_IWLWIFI_6000G2A=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LINUX_FIRMWARE_IWLWIFI_6000G2B=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LINUX_FIRMWARE_IWLWIFI_7260=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LINUX_FIRMWARE_IWLWIFI_7265D=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LINUX_FIRMWARE_IWLWIFI_8000C=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LINUX_FIRMWARE_IWLWIFI_8265=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LINUX_FIRMWARE_RALINK_RT73=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LINUX_FIRMWARE_RALINK_RT2XX=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LINUX_FIRMWARE_RTL_81XX=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LINUX_FIRMWARE_RTL_87XX=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LINUX_FIRMWARE_RTL_88XX=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LINUX_FIRMWARE_RTL_8169=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ACPID=y
BR2_PACKAGE_DBUS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ZLIB=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LIBFFI=y
BR2_PACKAGE_PCRE=y
BR2_PACKAGE_PCRE_UCP=y
BR2_PACKAGE_READLINE=y
BR2_PACKAGE_WPA_SUPPLICANT=y
BR2_PACKAGE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_DBUS_NEW=y
BR2_PACKAGE_KMOD=y
BR2_PACKAGE_UTIL_LINUX=y
BR2_PACKAGE_UTIL_LINUX_LIBMOUNT=y
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2=y
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_4=y
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_SIZE="120M"
# BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_TAR is not set
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_GENIMAGE=y
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable `UCLIBC_HAS_BSD_ERR` in uClibc.

You have a custom uClibc configuration. That falls squarely in the "you know what you are doing" category, since it allows you to remove features that other packages rely on.

In this case, util-linux relies on the non-Posix `err.h` include. This is only installed if `UCLIBC_HAS_BSD_ERR` is enabled in the uClibc configuration.

There is a high risk of running into similar issues with a custom uClibc configuration.

Comment: Yep, that was it. I got past this problem and into others, which I will post as separate questions if I can't resolve them. Thank you.

Comment: Questions like this are not really suitable for StackOverflow, you're better off asking them on the buildroot IRC channel (#buildroot on Freenode) or on the mailing list.